# Trimming or formatting an asp net hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, hyperlink, trim

As the title says: I want to trim or format a very long hyperlink. if the text is to long, I want the code to know that and replace the remaining strings with "..." for example: "averylongemailaccountexample@example.com". as soon as "account" starts, I want it to be replaced with "..."

I've tried trim, but it does not work.

C#:

```
var getContact = _ecSystem.GetContact(ContactId.Value);
    hlEmail.Text = getContact.Email.Trim(); //getContact.Email is a string.
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hlEmail" NavigateUrl="#"  />
```

Comment: `Trim` just removes the spaces from the begining/end of a string. So,what you want basically is replacing `averylongemailaccountexample@example.com` with `averylongemailaccount...@example.com`?

Comment: Is this a pattern all email addresses use or do you want to split the address on known words?

Comment: If the email is longer than 20 characters long, I want the ending to be "..."

Comment: @Malphai - Why you are manipulating the actual data if its purpose is just to display on the UI? Just imagine you want to do something on click of this _hyperlink_ what you will pass `averylong.....` Will your DB understand that? Best way is to do it with *CSS*.

Comment: @RahulSingh If you have any suggestion, please create a post about it.

Comment: Not req. @A.Tapper has already explained you that approach :)

Comment: It does work now ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the regular [SubString method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
var emailaddress = getContact.Email.Trim();
hlEmail.Text = emailaddress.Length > 20 ? emailaddress.SubString(0, 17) + "..." : emailaddress;
```

But as @RahulSingh said the most elegant way to do this is by using [css and the text-overflow property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp), then limit the size of the html container the link is within.

```
<a style="text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 50px; float: left; overflow: hidden;" href="mailto:averylongemailaccountexample@example.com">averylongemailaccountexample@example.com</a>
```

Comment: What? There is no option for substring in IntelliSense?

Comment: I cannot use an <a> tag, I have to use <asp:HyperLink>.

Comment: the <asp:HyperLink> will be rendered as an anchor tag, so you could just stick the style to it and give it a width if you so wish... :-)

Comment: @Malphai So what didn't work, C# approach or the css?

Comment: The CSS approach. I think it has to do something with my containers.

Comment: @Malphai I've updated the example above with an artificial limit to the container size so the ellipsis appear... here is a live example; https://jsfiddle.net/d80hz4ve/1/